# Kubernetes my-nginx example runs at 100% CPU on nodes

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, kubernetes

I deployed the Kubernetes nginx sample to AWS. In the Kube UI, I see the nodes running the nginx pod running at 100% CPU? Why is it doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Something in the pod must be in a loop.  If you run `top` on that node, I assume that shows some process consuming CPU - what is it?